# Getting data-attributes with jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, custom-data-attribute

Need to get extra data-attributes from the Mapbox API.

This is the autocomplete plugin I used.
https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/

(Python/Django backend)

Basically, I would like to push additional data like countrycode, city, country, etc to my database with an ajax call.

```
$("#hometown").autocomplete({

    dropdownWidth:'auto',
    appendMethod:'replace',
     valid: function () {
        return true;
 },
    source: [
        function (query, add) {
        var country;
        var suggestions = [];
        var result = {};
            // console.log(query);
            var url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9uYWxkbDkzIiwiYSI6ImNqZjAzaHgyeDBmbDUzM3BjdmlwcDcxZzgifQ.dFh3sKokufA_VwGiIE9QFQ&types=region,place&language=en-ZA';
            $.getJSON(url, function (resp) {

                console.log("API CALL SUCCESS");
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.features.length; i += 1) {
                    // console.log(resp.features[i].context[1]["text"]);
                   suggestions.push({"value": resp.features[i]['place_name'], "country": resp.features[i].context[1]["text"], "city": resp.features[i]["text"] });
                    country = resp.features[i].context[1]['text'];
                    // console.log(suggestions);

                 }

                 result["suggestions"] = add(suggestions);
                console.log(suggestions);
                add(suggestions);
                // console.log(suggestions)


            })
        }],
     getTitle:function(item){

        return item['value']
  // return '<div class="active" id="#homecountry-data" data-value="'+ item['value'] +'" data-country="'+ item['country'] +'" data-city="'+ item['city'] +'" style="display: none"></div>';
 },
});
```

A lot of the comments are just me experimenting and trying to figure out what works and what doesn't.

this is roughly what I have in mind for the ajax call.

```
$("#updatesettings").click(function() {
    console.log("I clicked")
    var home = $('#hometown').val();

        var settingsdata = {

            'home': home,
    };

        console.log(settingsdata);

    $('#updatesettings').prop('disabled', true);
    if (home.length >0){
        // $("#loader").show();
        ajaxCall('/modsettings', settingsdata,
            function(data){
            var succ = data.ok;
            if(succ == 'ok'){
                // $("#feedbackpopup").hide();
                alert("Settings Updated");
                // $('#contactName, #contactEmail, #contactMessage').val('');
                $('#updatesettings').prop('disabled', false);
            }

            if(succ == 'no'){
                alert("Oops. That didn't work. If this error continues please screenshot this and send me a message and I will fix it asap");
             $('#updatesettings').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        }
        );
    }
    else{
        $('#updatesettings').prop('disabled', false);
        alert("Please make sure all fields are complete.");
    }
});
```

I will reset the api key once I have it working. :)

Comment: what you could do is cache the api result. (```var result = {}; // populate result; // submit post adding result[$('#hometown').val()]```)  then on the user changing the autocomplete you return the index and then push the result to your post.

Comment: would actually combine the above with a more visual approach. user selects from the drop down and you populate disabled fields with the values or add to hidden fields for easier testing and handling. autocomplete on change lookup the record from the api call and then add the values to the fields as required

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this.

```
// AUTOCOMPLETE TRY 2

var city;
var country;
var long;
var lat;
var citysettings

// autocomplete with help from Pietz. DANKJEWEL!!!
$(function() {
 $('#hometown').autocomplete({
    minChars: 3,
     lookup: function (query, done) {
         // console.log(query);
         var result = {};
         var suggestions = [];
         // console.log(result)

         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             //CORS-enabled API
             url: "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + encodeURIComponent(query) + ".json?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9uYWxkbDkzIiwiYSI6ImNqZjAzaHgyeDBmbDUzM3BjdmlwcDcxZzgifQ.dFh3sKokufA_VwGiIE9QFQ&types=place&language=en-ZA",

             dataType: "json",

             success: function (json) {
                 console.log("API call successful.");

                 for (var i = 0; i < json.features.length; i += 1) {
                  console.log(json.features[i]['place_name']);
                  try {
                        suggestions.push({
                            "value": json.features[i]['place_name'],
                            "country": json.features[i].context[1]['text'],
                            "city": json.features[i]['text_en-ZA'],
                            "long": json.features[i].center[0],
                            "lat": json.features[i].center[1]
                        });

                    }
                    catch(err) {

                      suggestions.push({
                            "value": json.features[i]['place_name'],
                            "country": json.features[i].context[0]['text'],
                            "city": json.features[i]['text_en-ZA'],
                            "long": json.features[i].center[0],
                            "lat": json.features[i].center[1]
                        });


                    }

                   // var country = json.features[i].context[1]['text'];
                   // var city = json.features[i]['text'];
                   // long = json.features[i].center[0];
                   // lat = json.features[i].center[1];
                   // console.log(lat);
                 }
                 result["suggestions"] = suggestions;
                 done(result);
                 console.log(result);


                 // $('.autocomplete.suggestions').click(function () {
                 //     console.log(onclick);
                 //     console.log(country);
                 // });


             },


             error: function (ajaxContext) {
                 console.log(ajaxContext.responseText)
             }

         });

     },
         onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        city = suggestion.city;
        country = suggestion.country;
        long = suggestion.long;
        lat = suggestion.lat;

                citysettings = {
          "city": city,
          "country": country,
          "long": long,
          "lat": lat
    };

    },



     lookupLimit: 1

 });
 });

        $("#updatesettings").click(function () {

        console.log(citysettings);

});
```